# Flink1.16 High Availability Job Manager

Tags: apache-flink

We are setting up the high availability of job manager for flink jobs. below is the configurations, but getting the error.

```
configurations
-------------

kubernetes.cluster-id: retry-flink-cluster
high-availability: kubernetes
high-availability.storageDir: file:///opt/flink/recovery.txt
```

Error

```
2022-11-28 08:57:56.032 [main] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint  - Shutting KubernetesApplicationClusterEntrypoint down with application status FAILED. Diagnostics java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_OLD_HA_SERVICES
        at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory.createHAServices(KubernetesHaServicesFactory.java:37)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.highavailability.HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.createCustomHAServices(HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.java:296)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.highavailability.HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.createHighAvailabilityServices(HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.java:139)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.createHaServices(ClusterEntrypoint.java:439)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.initializeServices(ClusterEntrypoint.java:382)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:282)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.lambda$startCluster$1(ClusterEntrypoint.java:232)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.startCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:229)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runClusterEntrypoint(ClusterEntrypoint.java:729)
        at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.entrypoint.KubernetesApplicationClusterEntrypoint.main(KubernetesApplicationClusterEntrypoint.java:86)
```

Comment: The storageDir doesn't point to a durable storage, I think that should point to an S3 or HDFS location

Comment: I have the same issue with flink-kubernetes-operator. This field NoSuchFieldError: USE_OLD_HA_SERVICES was removed in flink 1.16, but error occurs with setting: flinkVersion: v1_15

Comment: It looks like a bug. I created [FLINK-30313](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-30313) to cover it. It would be good if you could add more context in the Jira issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting the issue. We already merged a solution for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-30222